# Can I apply Technical Analysis techniques from trading on performance statistics from servers/other computing hardware

Tags: time-series

Very briefly, I am a long-time sysadmin with quite a lot of exposure to monitoring tools as part of my job. Recently I have also been teaching myself about Forex and trading generally.

The latter has introduced me to Technical Analysis (MA/EMAs, Bollinger Bands, MACD).

I am curious as to whether these Technical Analysis techniques could be applied to server performance statistics (e.g. CPU load) in projecting/predicting alarm situations with some degree of accuracy.

Sorry if this is the wrong place to ask, but it's not clear where I should ask this given that it crosses a few subject domains for which SE have dedicated boards.

Comment: This is just my opinion but the charts and metrics technical analysis relies on are, for the most part, astatistical, voodoo heuristics with little or no theoretical motivation, rigor, whatever you want to call it. Their only advantages are that they are easily developed, implemented and visualized in the endless graphics technical analysts pore over. If you want to develop meaningful forecasts of server performance characteristics, build some sort of predictive statistical model.

Comment: This *is* probably the right place to ask--but I suspect you will find that this community overwhelmingly agrees with @DJohnson.  Supposing, hypothetically, that Technical Analysis methods did have some value for asset analysis, I am aware of no evidence and no theory that suggests they would apply directly to any other kinds of data.